# Strange behavior with acts_as_taggable_on's tagged_with method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to find all records that have similar tags to the currently viewed record. 
My controller has:

```
  def show
    @tattoo =Tattoo.find(params[:id])
    tags = @tattoo.style_list.join(", ")
    @tattoos = Tattoo.tagged_with(tags, :any => true).limit(6)
  end
```

(bonus points if anyone can tell me how to randomize the order of records in the arrary)
My view just loops through the array.

Anyway, it works almost all the time but I noticed it breaks occasionally and while troubleshooting I found that it breaks when I use `tagged_with("jesse smith", :any => true)` but it works when I try `tagged_with("jason stephan", :any => true)` or `tagged_with("black ink", :any => true)`

So each term has a space in it but for whatever reason 'jesse smith' kills the action.

My console shows that I have a routing error too:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tattoos", :member_id=>nil, :id=>#<Tattoo id: 170, description: "", status: "approved", member_id: nil, created_at: "2011-10-25 23:08:17", updated_at: "2011-11-17 16:56:55", file_file_name: "starry-eyed-rabid-squirrelweb.jpg", file_content_type: "image/jpeg", file_file_size: 294782, file_updated_at: "2011-10-25 23:08:17", album_id: nil, position: 116, favorite_count: 0, share_count: 1, file_remote_url: "http://www.jessesmithtattoos.com/wp-content/gallery...">}):
    22:    <ol class="small_tattoos">
    23:     <% @tattoos.each do |t| %>
    24:       <li>
    25:       <%= link_to image_tag(t.file.url(:tiny),:alt=>"#{t.style_list}, rtattoos, tattoos"), member_tattoo_path(t.member, t) %>
    26:       </li>
    27:     <% end %>
    28:    </ol>
  app/views/index/show.html.erb:25:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_index_show_html_erb___1839804211534816245_69842632179360__4333294961394575926'
  app/views/index/show.html.erb:23:in `block in _app_views_index_show_html_erb___1839804211534816245_69842632179360__4333294961394575926'
  app/views/index/show.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_index_show_html_erb___1839804211534816245_69842632179360__4333294961394575926'
```

So why does the one term cause a routing error and not the others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have problem with path helper:

```
member_tattoo_path(t.member, t)
```

I see in your error description that

```
:member_id=>nil
```

So it turns out that tattoo tagged with jesse smith hasn't corresponding association with name 'member', and path helper, which need valid id, throws exception.

Comment: Ohh man you know what? Im dumb I should have seen that and realized that I didnt include the if/else statement in that view, I think it's time for a break. Thanks!